# How to do TAB spacing while inserting values in a table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to tab space my data while inserting through sql in phpmyADMIN.
What should I do?

```
INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `question_name`, `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`, `answer6`, `answer`, `category_id`) VALUES(90,'C<br>       java', '1', '2', '3', '4', '', '', '3', 2);
```

Comment: If you're asking for the horizontal tab character it is `\t`

Comment: can you also help me how to print  '  character ?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string up and place a tab in between: `'some' + CHAR(9) + 'string'`. Note that 9 is the ASCII code for a horizontal tab. Perhaps easier is `'some\tstring'`, which is syntax common to many other languages.

See table 9.1 here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html